# Microsoft.VisualSutdio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc NuGet package install fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

In Visual Studio 2019 I am trying to install some NuGet packages in order to fix the automatic scaffolding (creating controller with views in ASP.NET MVC 5).

If I try:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc -v 3.1.5
```

Then 2 'yellow' errors occur:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.3.1.5 : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration [3.1.5, )' does not exist in project 'SampleProject'
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.3.1.5 : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration [3.1.5, )' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\x\SampleProject\packages'
```

The supposedly missing package is already installed.

And 1 'red' error:

```
Install-Package : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\x\SampleProject\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.3.1.5\Templates/Identity_Versioned/Bootstrap3/Pages/Account/
Manage/Account.Manage.TwoFactorAuthentication.cs.cshtml'.
At line:1 char:1
```

Is there a way to avoid the hard dependency on the 'TwoFactorAuthentication.cs.cshtml' presented in the 'red' error?  The project doesn't use 2FA.

Comment: Do you mean that this error occurs when Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc is installed based on the default ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) project template? If so, what is the nuget repo source on your side, nuget gallery? I tried on my side but did not reproduce your error, can you provide some more detailed steps; and the title of your question says that the installation failed, But the text also mentions "The supposedly missing package is already installed." (Although the installation failed from the error report.), Can you explain this clearly.

Comment: By the way, for the installation process of this package, if you are based on the nuget source of nuget gallery, you should not encounter this strange problem of 2FA. You can check if there is a problem with the nuget cache, such as by cleaning the cache:

[Clearing local folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

Comment: From the first error, it looks like it didn't find the package in your local source, please check the source in package manager or global nuget.config.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT - thanks for all the feedback.  I did clear my local folders but the install still failed.  I will try to clarify my question.

Comment: Hi John, is there any update on this issue? :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT - I never did find a solution.  Had to step back to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT - I ended up installing Visual Studio 2022 and don't have any issues.